# How to convert a short sentence to adjective

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

I have a protocol that (1) can delegate storage and computation (2) can delegate computation unlimited number of times

**Question:** How can I convert (1) and (2) into adjectives?

OR

How can I mention them in a list as two separate properties of a protocol?

Comment: Are those attributes of the same protocol or of two different protocols?

Comment: @VictorBazarov The same protocol

Comment: Perhaps folks in the application area of SE could help?  It's technology-specific, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can use any of the following:

> a) *a storage and unlimited number of computation delegation **protocol***
>   b) *a **protocol delegating** storage and an unlimited number of computations*
>   c) *a **protocol supporting** a storage and unlimited number of computation **delegation***
>   d) *a **protocol supporting a delegation** of storage and (of) an unlimited number of computations*
>   e) *a **protocol supporting a delegation** of storage and (of) unlimited computation*

I marked the main words in bold. The head noun in a) (*protocol*) is modified attributively (i.e. we pile other nouns, attributively, in front of the head noun. Alternatives b) to e) are post-modified, i.e., the head noun comes first. Alternative b) uses the participle *delegating*, whereas c) to e) use *supporting* (and move *delegation* to inside of the *supporting*-clause accordingly). Alternative e) considers *computation* as an abstract noun, so the *number of* part was removed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Thank you very much. I have a question  somehow unrelated. Can I replace "an unlimited number of times" with "an unlimited times"?

Comment: I think you may use it, but without *an*. It doesn't sound as good as *an unlimited number of times* to me, though.

Comment: I just thought that protocols **establish** rather than **support**, but I can be wrong.